# hash the password to md5 in the database

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter, md5

I need your help very much!
There is a ready-made authorization form. When the application is launched, a database is created, this database is filled in manually via db browser. It needs to be filled in with usernames and passwords. After that, you need to make sure that the passwords become hashed. Accordingly, when entering the login and password, a window should pop out that the authorization was successful.
Help please
Below is the code

```
from tkinter import *
import sqlite3
from tkinter import messagebox as mb
import hashlib

conn = sqlite3.connect('sotrudniki.db')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users(
    login TEXT,
    pswd TEXT);""")
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM users")

clr = "#072f41"
fg = "#ffffff"
entry ="#355e7e"

aut = Tk()
aut.title("er")
aut["bg"] = clr
aut.geometry('320x320')
aut.resizable(width=0, height=0)
def vhod():
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE login = '" + enlog.get() + "' AND pswd = '" + enpw.get() + "'")
    res1 = cur.fetchone()
    if res1 != None:
        mb.showinfo("Успешно", "Вы вошли!")
        aut.destroy()

    elif enlog.get() == "" or enpw.get() == "":
        mb.showerror("Error", "Error")
    
    else:
        mb.showerror("Error", "Error")
        enlog.delete(0, END)
        enpw.delete(0, END)
    
lb = Label(aut, text = "AUTH", font = ("Times", 25), bg=clr, fg=fg)
lb.pack(pady=20)

lblog = Label(aut, text = "LOGIN", font = ("Times", 18), bg=clr, fg=fg)
lblog.pack()

enlog = Entry(aut, font = ("Times", 15), fg=fg, bg=entry)
enlog.pack()

lbpw = Label(aut, text = "PASWWORD",
                font = ("Times", 18), bg=clr, fg=fg)
lbpw.pack()

enpw = Entry(aut, font = ("Times", 15), fg=fg, bg=entry,
                show = "*")
enpw.pack()

bt = Button(aut, text = "Go", font = ("Times", 25), fg=fg, bg=entry, width = 10, command = vhod)
bt.pack(pady = 25, padx = 10)

aut.mainloop()
```

The password must be hashed

Comment: It is not clear what your problem is.

Comment: The problem is that I do not know what to do to have a hashed password in my database

Comment: Do you mean that you don't know how to create a hashed password into a table in a database?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I mean. I need to add a username and password to the database, and after the function, all passwords must be hashed

Comment: In general I would not recommend to use an MD5 hash to store passwords. Use a password-hashing function like bcrypt instead.

Comment: It is not a valid question in StackOverflow if you ask for code from scratch (as your posted code does not related to inserting credentials into a table).  Study documents on `hashlib.md5()` and try to do it yourself and post any problem you come across.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this:

```
import hashlib

hashedPwd = hashlib.md5(enpw.get().encode())
```

Insert the hashedPwd to the database. If someone tries to login, you should hash his password too and check for equality with the hashed Password in the database.

But the hashedPwd will be in Bytes, not as String.

Comment: And where exactly in the database to insert hashedPwd?

Comment: Insert it where you want to store the user data. Something like that:
INSERT INTO users (login, pswd) VALUES (enlog.get(), hashedPwd)

But you have to convert hashedPwd to a string or change the database column pswd to bytes.

Comment: You need to call `.digest()` or `.hexdigest()` on the result of `hashlib.md5(...)` in order to get the result.  `hashedPwd` is not the string result, it is a `hashlib.HASH` object.